# JSON direct from DB vs Framework abstraction?

Tags: php, sql, json

One of our team has proposed an API design which outputs JSON directly from an SQL query. The benefit is absolute speed at a cost of using the framework implementation of preferred DB access.

For the purpose of this question, this is using a PHP framework and an SQL database, but is essentially agnostic. The team is very strong in SQL but are not DBAs.

The new API has dozens of collection resources and hundreds of endpoint permutations. Once received by the framework router, several classes are required to accept, filter, abstract and process a final SQL query. The result object returned is further processed and returned as an application JSON response.

The suggestion mooted is that for most of the collection resources and 75% of all possible endpoints an SQL query (albeit a potentially complex one) can generate the required output with no etraneous data. This can then easily be converted to JSON and delivered by the basic architecture of any framework.

**NB**: a framework **will** be used for the usual benefits & SQL queries will be version controlled and DB stored.

**NB**: the framework will still sanitise the input and the output will be verified before sending the the client.

**NB**: speed is critical and will process millions of calls.

For certain circumstances and a suitable use-case, is this an elegant solution with some minor scalability issues or a dangerous precedent?

Comment: Different database engines handle JSON differently. Which database engine are you planning on using?

Comment: We're not planning to use JSON objects within the DB, but the result set output is intended to be an array. This may require more than one result set to build an array of arrays which will then be converted to JSON.